# Is there a way to declare printer settings in SVG?

Tags: svg, printing

I had a scaling issue on printing an SVG file that is exported from Inkscape. [It turns out](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/120149/how-to-fix-change-inkscape-scale-factor-while-exporting-into-svg?noredirect=1#comment179132_120149) that the issue is caused by wrong/incompatible printer settings.

Is there a way to propose the printer settings from within an SVG file where the application *must* take in consideration upon printing that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: *No, it's not possible.*

First of all, an SVG file is not intended for print. It's a simple vector file format used for web graphics. It can't even have a color profile or multiple pages.

Even if we were talking about a PDF (which is intended for print) it's not possible to force printer settings like *paper format, orientation, fit to printer margins/actual size, grayscale/color, resolution* etc.

In this case, it might sound like a good idea to be able to do that, but seen from the user's point of view it would be very annoying if documents didn't behave in the same way and constantly tried to override the user's preferred printer settings.

Furthermore, different printers could have different settings available. I'm not sure, but I don't think there is a global standard for this. There could be manufacturers who uses their own standard.

I do understand why you want this. I often send designs for approval to my clients and they tell me everything looks kinda small - they are unaware of the *fit to printer margins/actual size* issue, but I can't control their printer, so I have to instruct them to print at *actual size/100%*.

Comment: The only permanent solution for such a facility seems to be achieved by adding some custom attributes to the SVG to define the printing settings and write a custom printing server application.